# Понимание работы backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Очень хочется разобраться с backbone, почитал стандартную документацию, полазил по хабру и другим сайтам, но так и не нашёл нормального примера, который поможет понять работу с этим фреймворком. То есть, вернее, простые какие-то моменты понятны, но всё это пока не нужно, а самое главное что меня интересует - связь с сервером - отправка данных и обработка ответов от сервера.

Если по стандартному на jquery я всегда вешал событие и вызывал ajax таким образом:

```
//защита от отправки 2 и более запросов одновременно
//на случай если, например, пользователь нажимает 2+ раза на кнопку отправки запроса
if (!blockedAjaxRepeat){
  $.ajax({
            url: AJAX_HOST,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            // rq - название модуля, который будем вызывать на сервере
            // data - данные, которые идут на сервер
            data: { rq: rq, data: data },
            beforeSend: function(){
                blockedAjaxRepeat = true;
            },
            complete: function(data){
                blockedAjaxRepeat = false;
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //сервер отправляет json данные 
                // status - статус завершения(0 - ок, иначе - какая-то ошибка)             
                if (data.status == 0){
                    //действие при успешном завершении
                } else {
                    //действие если произошла ошибка валидации или другая
                }
            }
        });
   }
```

Теперь не понимаю как это правильно написать на backbone, например если я пишу простую авторизацию на сайте(поле логин и пароль). Если есть какой-то готовый пример, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь можно найти ответ:
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332735/2114360)

По сути процесс авторизации порождает модель авторизации. Соответственно в рамках backbone можно создать модель и вьюху для нее, в которой будут обрабатываться html-элементы, их события и обработка колбэков